# How to pull a file with python code in Unix env

Tags: python, unix

I have the file in this place

```
/home/unica/app/Affinium/Campaign/partitions/partition1/scripts/runscripts/campaigns/cnyr/dev
```

I want to call it here.like.

```
 with open('/home/unica/app/Affinium/Campaign/partitions/partition1/scripts/runscripts/campaigns/cnyr/dev/CNYR_DM_TM_CAMPAIGN_WAVES.csv','rb') as csvfile
```

But it is throwing error as syntax error.Also how can I simplify the path name into some alias name.

Comment: Without showing more code, I'm going to guess it's because you are missing the ending colon `:`

Comment: You are missing a colon at the end of the line

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
fileName = '/home/unica/app/Affinium/Campaign/partitions/partition1/scripts/runscripts/campaigns/cnyr/dev/CNYR_DM_TM_CAMPAIGN_WAVES.csv'

with open(fileName, 'rb') as csvfile: # notice that the line must end with a ':'
    for line in csvfile:
        # do something
```

Or even better, use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module:

```
import csv

with open(fileName, 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|') # specify delimiter, etc.
    for row in reader:
        # do something
```